# NAN in calculating distance between two Point

Tags: php, gps, latitude-longitude

I am using haversine formula in distance calculation between two point.
Some time that result was Come.some times its getting NAN result.please help 
here this my code

```
function distanceCalculation($point1_lat, $point1_long, $lat, $lng, $unit = 'km', $decimals = 3)
    {

        $degrees = rad2deg(acos((sin(deg2rad($point1_lat)) * sin(deg2rad($lat))) + (cos(deg2rad($point1_lat)) * cos(deg2rad($lat)) * cos(deg2rad($point1_long - $lng)))));


        switch ($unit) {
            case 'km':
                $distance = $degrees * 111.13384;
                break;
            case 'mi':
                $distance = $degrees * 69.05482;
                break;
            case 'nmi':
                $distance = $degrees * 59.97662;
        }
        return round($distance, $decimals);


    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function isValid($arg = 0) 
{
    return (is_nan($arg) || is_infinite($arg))? 0 :$arg;
}

return isValid(round($distance, $decimals));
```

Use this function it checks is_nan and is_infinite.